# Single Logout not working with multiple SP - Spring Security SAML

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have `Springboot` app acting as an SP built by following [this example](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-boot-security-saml-sample/tree/poc/keycloak-saml-idp).Below is my usecase -

1. Using `Keycloak` as an IDP.
2. Launched SP-1 at port 3030 having EntityId `login-app-one`.
3. Launched SP-2 at port 4040 having EntityId `login-app-two`.
4. Registered these two instances in `Keycloak` as two clients in same realm named `demo`.
5. Created dummy user in Keycloak.
6. Logged in to SP-1 successfully.
7. Logged in to SP-2 successfully.
8. I can see two sessions created in Keycloak admin console.
9. Tried `Global Logout` from SP-1, Keycloak sessions are still active.
10. Tried `Global Logout` from SP-2, Keycloak session are still active.
11. Sometimes, doing a Global logout from SP-2 lands me on SP-1 after redirection from Keycloak. This is weird. (Found the reason for this behaviour, the my update below)

Important thing to note here is that if I have a single SP logged in, the Global logout works fine. I'm trying to achieve simple SSO and SLO using multiple SPs but it does not work.

I suspect the problem is with my `Spring SAML` app. I don't see any errors on the Springboot console.

**Update**:

1. SLO is working well if springboot app is hosted on some domain. I deployed two instances of my Springboot app and keycloak server on a docker container (using https://labs.play-with-docker.com/). So now the question is why it doesn't work on `localhost`.
2. Logging out SP-1 lands me on SP-2 because the `Front Channel Logout` option was enabled in the client settings in my Keycloak server. Because of this, Keycloak logs out all the clients one by one through a browser redirect.